# Variable Undefined in Click Event Listener

Tags: javascript

The Variable slide_titles and slide_background are logging out as undefined in the Click Event Listener. Why is this?

Im trying to add and remove classes using classList. It's not working because the global variables aren't visible inside the on click EventListener.

html

```
 <div class="product-type">
    <ul>
        <li class="slide__title selected">Cars</li>
        <li class="slide__title" >Motorcycles</li>
        <li class="slide__title">Power Equiptment</li>
        <li class="slide__title">Marine</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

    <ul id="slides">
        <li class="slide cars"></li>
        <li class="slide bikes"></li>
        <li class="slide mower"></li>   
        <li class="slide boat"></li>
    </ul>
```

javascript

```
    var slide_titles = document.querySelectorAll('.slide__title');
var slide_background = document.querySelectorAll('.slide');


function removeSelected() {
  for(var i = 0; i < slide_titles.length; i++) {
    if(slide_titles[i].className.indexOf('selected') != -1) {
      console.log("remove");
      slide_titles[i].classList.remove("selected");
    }
  }
}


var clickEvent = function(index) {
slide_titles[i].addEventListener("click", () => {
        removeSelected();
        slide_background[i].classList.add("show");
        slide_titles[i].classList.add("selected");
        console.log(slide_background[i]);

  });
}


   for(var i = 0; i < slide_titles.length; i++) {
      clickEvent(i);
   }
```

here is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/6yjfdftc/1/

Comment: Vanilla JS please!

Comment: Try changing .slide__title and .slide to li.slide__title and li.slide

Comment: My guess is because the JavaScript is executing before the HTML had loaded. Try wrapping you code in an event handler fired off from the window.onload event

Comment: I have made those changes unfortunately the error is still occuring

Comment: Thank you for your help, this issue has been fixed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's logging undefined because `i` is undefined in that scope. Since you pass `i` to it in your for loop, try this:

```
var clickEvent = function(index) {
    slide_titles[index].addEventListener("click", () => {
        removeSelected();
        slide_background[index].classList.add("show");
        slide_titles[index].classList.add("selected");
        console.log(slide_background[index]);
    });
}
```

Here's an updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6yjfdftc/6/).

Comment: i have gone through and made those changes to the clickEvent function. nothing is logging now.

Comment: Have you checked out the fiddle? `index` is only used in the `clickEvent` function

Comment: apologies, this has fixed the issue. My mistake. Thank you for your help.